# Dell SonicWALL SSL VPN applying a /32 (255.255.255.255) subnet mask

Tags: vpn, sonicwall, sslvpn

I currently have setup my SonicWALL TZ215 with SSLVPN.

I am connecting from my 2015 MacBook using the SonicWALL Mobile Connection application.

The application correctly connects, but when I run `ifconfig`, I can see the following:

```
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.16.191 --> 192.168.16.191 netmask 0xffffffff
```

My network is on `192.168.16.0`, so I correctly receive an address from the range (provided by the SonicWALL) but I am getting given a `0xffffffff` (hexadecimal converts to 255.255.255.255) subnet.

The SonicWALL is running firmware 5.8. Do you nave any ideas how I can provide a different subnet on the SSLVPN connection as I can't see anywhere that I apply the subnet mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I needed to apply allowed networks underneath the user. I applied the `network` object here.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up and looking for an answer.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up and looking for an answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin, Done - Apologies - It was too soon when I originally answered the question, annoying how SE sites do that.